# Why does `Array<Value>, Value` not work for fetching the array value type?

Tags: typescript

I have the following type declaration:

```
function eachr<Subject extends Array<Value>, Value>(
    subject: Subject,
    callback: (
        this: Subject,
        value: Value,
        key: number,
        subject: Subject
    ) => void | boolean
): Subject {
    // contrived
    return subject
}
```

However, when one calls it with:

```
eachr(['a', 'b', 'c'], function(value, key) {})
```

The type of `value` is `{}`, whereas I expected it to be `string`.

I can modify it to the following:

```
function eachr<Subject extends any[]>(
    subject: Subject,
    callback: (
        this: Subject,
        value: Subject[number],
        key: number,
        subject: Subject
    ) => void | boolean
): Subject {
    return subject
}
```

Which seems to work.

As well as the following:

```
function eachr<
    Subject extends any[],
    Key extends number,
    Value extends Subject[Key]
>(
    subject: Subject,
    callback: (
        this: Subject,
        value: Value,
        key: Key,
        subject: Subject
    ) => void | boolean
): Subject {
    // contrived
    return subject
}
```

However, I don't understand why they work, but my first attempt does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have only changed (in the first version of function) the type of `subject` parameter like this:

```
subject: Subject & Array<Value>
```

The reason is: a type parameter is never inferred when it is put in *type parameters list* which is `<Subject extends Array<Value>, Value>`, but it is inferred from the *regular parameters list* which is `subject: /**/, callback: /**/`. This means that `Value` was inferred from `callback`, where TS had no chance to infer it to something other than `{}`

Comment: Could this also be what is at play here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54008406/130638

Comment: @balupton Oh those code pieces looks overwhelmingly big. I doubt anyone will go through it. You have 31k scores you definitely know MCVE, don't you?