# Why was `Subject & Array<Value>` necessary for a compatible overload signature?

Tags: typescript

I am getting:

> Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.ts(2394)

On:

```
/** Iterate through an Array. */
export default function eachr<Value>(
    subject: Array<Value>,
    callback: IteratorCallback<typeof subject, number, Value>
): typeof subject
```

Of this entire snippet:

```
export interface IteratorCallback<Subject, Key, Value> {
    (this: Subject, value: Value, key: Key, subject: Subject): void | boolean
}

/** Iterate through an Array. */
export default function eachr<Value>(
    subject: Array<Value>,
    callback: IteratorCallback<typeof subject, number, Value>
): typeof subject

/** Iterate through an Object. */
export default function eachr<RecordKey extends keyof any, Value>(
    subject: Record<RecordKey, Value>,
    callback: IteratorCallback<typeof subject, RecordKey, Value>
): typeof subject

/** Iterate through the subject. */
export default function eachr<RecordKey extends keyof any, Value>(
    input: Array<Value> | Record<RecordKey, Value>,
    callback: IteratorCallback<typeof input, RecordKey | number, Value>
): typeof input {
    if (Array.isArray(input)) {
        // Array
        const subject = input as Array<Value>
        for (let key = 0; key < subject.length; ++key) {
            const value = subject[key]
            if (callback.call(subject, value, key, subject) === false) {
                break
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Object
        const subject = input as Record<RecordKey, Value>
        for (const key in subject) {
            if (subject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                const value = subject[key]
                if (callback.call(subject, value, key, subject) === false) {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Return
    return input
}
```

I could make it work by changing it to:

```
/** Iterate through an Array. */
export default function eachr<Subject extends Array<Value>, Value>(
    subject: Subject & Array<Value>,
    callback: IteratorCallback<typeof subject, number, Value>
): typeof subject
```

**However, I don't understand why that fixed it. What was the problem, and why did that change make the problem go away?**

What is even more surprising to me, is that if I apply that same change to a pure object iterator function, it causes it to fail:

```
/** Iterate through an Object. */
export default function eachrObject<
    Subject extends Record<RecordKey, Value>,
    RecordKey extends keyof any,
    Value
>(
    subject: Subject & Record<RecordKey, Value>,
    callback: IteratorCallback<typeof subject, RecordKey, Value>
): typeof subject {
    for (const key in subject) {
        if (subject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const value = subject[key]
            // above fails with: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Record<RecordKey, Value>' has no index signature.ts(7017)
            // below fails with: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RecordKey'.ts(2345)
            if (callback.call(subject, value, key, subject) === false) {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return subject
}
```

Whereas this works:

```
/** Iterate through an Object. */
export default function eachrObject<RecordKey extends keyof any, Value>(
    subject: Record<RecordKey, Value>,
    callback: IteratorCallback<typeof subject, RecordKey, Value>
): typeof subject {
    for (const key in subject) {
        if (subject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const value = subject[key]
            if (callback.call(subject, value, key, subject) === false) {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return subject
}
```

Yet both forms work fine for the Array iterator:

```
/** Iterate through an Array. */
export default function eachrArray<Subject extends Array<Value>, Value>(
    subject: Subject & Array<Value>,
    callback: IteratorCallback<typeof subject, number, Value>
): typeof subject {
    for (let key = 0; key < subject.length; ++key) {
        const value = subject[key]
        if (callback.call(subject, value, key, subject) === false) {
            break
        }
    }
    return subject
}

/** Iterate through an Array. */
export default function eachrArray<Value>(
    subject: Array<Value>,
    callback: IteratorCallback<typeof subject, number, Value>
): typeof subject {
    for (let key = 0; key < subject.length; ++key) {
        const value = subject[key]
        if (callback.call(subject, value, key, subject) === false) {
            break
        }
    }
    return subject
}
```

**So how come the change to `Subject extends Array<Value>` was necessary for overloading compatibility for the areay iterator, yet `Subject extends Record<RecordKey, Value>` breaks the object iterator?**

Sorry for the shear amount of code here, this was the minimum use case I could bring it down to, that contained all the considerations at play.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, this is a lot to wade through, and I don't think I can answer exactly why you've gotten things to work.  In my opinion, your overload signatures should both fail.  Let's look at a super simple overload/implementation example:

```
function foo(x: string): void; // narrower, okay 
function foo(x: string | number | boolean): void; // wider, error
function foo(x: string | number): void {} // impl
```

Notice how the second overload signature gives the error that it is not compatible with the implementation signature.  That's because the overload's `x` is a *wider* type than the implementation's `x`.  And overloads require *narrower* types.

Also note how in general (since [`--strictFunctionTypes` was introduced in TypeScript 2.6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#strict-function-types)) function types are *contravariant* in their parameter types.  That results in the following behavior:

```
type StringAccepter = (x: string) => void;
const helloAccepter: StringAccepter = (x: "hello") => {}; // error
const stringOrNumberAccepter: StringAccepter = (x: string | number) => {}; // okay
```

`helloAccepter` is not a valid `StringAccepter` because `"hello"` is narrower than `string`, while `stringOrNumberAccepter` *is* a valid `StringAccepter` because `string | number` is wider than `string`.  And thus function parameters becoming wider make their functions narrower and vice versa:

```
function bar(cb: (x: "hello")=>void): void; // error, cb is too wide because x is too narrow
function bar(cb: (x: string | number)=>void): void; // okay, cb is narrower because x is wider 
function bar(cb: StringAccepter): void {} // impl
```

So I'd expect both of your overloads to fail, since the implementation signature's `callback` type (`IteratorCallback<typeof input, RecordKey | number, Value>`) is actually narrower than either of your call signature's `callback` types.

At this point, instead of trying to slog through your possible solution involving an extra `Subject` type parameter and understanding why some things work and some things don't (which makes my brain hurt... maybe there's a compiler bug?  maybe not?  who knows), I'll instead go with the solution I'd suggest... make the implementation signature truly wide enough to support both call signatures:

```
/** Iterate through an Array. */
export function eachr<Value>(
  subject: Array<Value>,
  callback: IteratorCallback<typeof subject, number, Value>
): typeof subject

/** Iterate through an Object. */
export function eachr<RecordKey extends keyof any, Value>(
  subject: Record<RecordKey, Value>,
  callback: IteratorCallback<typeof subject, RecordKey, Value>
): typeof subject

/** Iterate through the subject. */
export function eachr<RecordKey extends keyof any, Value>(
  input: Array<Value> | Record<RecordKey, Value>, 
  // here is the change
  callback: IteratorCallback<Array<Value>, number, Value> |
    IteratorCallback<Record<RecordKey, Value>, RecordKey, Value>
): typeof input {
  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    // Array
    const subject = input as Array<Value>
    // a new assertion:
    const cb = callback as IteratorCallback<Array<Value>, number, Value>;
    for (let key = 0; key < subject.length; ++key) {
      const value = subject[key]
      if (cb.call(subject, value, key, subject) === false) {
        break
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Object
    const subject = input as Record<RecordKey, Value>
    // a new assertion:
    const cb = callback as IteratorCallback<Record<RecordKey, Value>, RecordKey, Value>;
    for (const key in subject) {
      if (subject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const value = subject[key]
        if (cb.call(subject, value, key, subject) === false) {
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Return
  return input
}
```

The difference is the `callback` parameter on the implementation signature is a true union of the analogous types of the `callback` parameter on each call signature.  Additionally the implementation itself needs to do a narrowing assertion for `callback` to `cb` in much the same way as the assertion you're already doing for `input` to `subject`.

Now the compiler should be happy.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: The type assertions on `input` are unnecessary in the first place... I came to the same conclusion that neither overload should have worked. Very confusing behavior.

Comment: Good point about the unnecessary type assertions on `input`; control flow analysis should handle that narrowing.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

This has to do with how union types work. The problem originates from the last (accumulative) overload:

```
callback: IteratorCallback<typeof input, RecordKey | number, Value>
```

Because `input` here is of type `Array<Value> | Record<RecordKey, Value>`, the definition for `callback` constructed this way allows 4 possible combinations to exist:

```
IteratorCallback<Array<Value>, RecordKey, Value>
IteratorCallback<Array<Value>, number, Value>
IteratorCallback<Record<RecordKey, Value>, RecordKey, Value>
IteratorCallback<Record<RecordKey, Value>, number, Value>
```

but only 2 of them are valid according to your preceding overload definition

**Solution**

This can be fixed by saying `callback` will be either one of these two types:

```
callback: IteratorCallback<Array<Value>, number, Value> | IteratorCallback<Record<RecordKey, Value>, RecordKey, Value>
```

This takes care of the *Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation* error.
However, another issue has been uncovered: TypeScript doesn't make the connection between the type of provided `input` and the `callback` that goes with it. Because the last overload still uses union types — two for `input` and two for `callback` — there are 4 scenarios TypeScript thinks can happen. It seems the most popular workaround for this problem is just using a type assertion.